# How to correctly display image in Kotlin from firebase storage and firestore

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm working on a project that use Firebase Storage and Firestore. I added function that allows to upload images from phone gallery to Storage and storage url of this image is saved in Firestore with some other informations. Everything works fine, even the image url in firestore displays selected image correctly in browser. The problem is when i try to set this image to ImageView using Glide or Picasso, because it only shows a blank image/placeholder. This is how my repository functions looks to add and download data:

```
override fun addProject(uri: Uri, project: Project) {
    val imagesRef = storage.reference.child("images/${uri.lastPathSegment}")
    Log.d("firebase ref url", imagesRef.toString())
    imagesRef.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener {
        Log.d("firebase image", "Succesfully uploaded")
        imagesRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri->
                project.photoUrl = uri.toString()
                db.collection("projects").add(project)
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Log.d("firebase image", "Unsuccessfully uploaded")
    }
}




override suspend fun getProjects(): List<Project> {
    val projectList = mutableListOf<Project>()
    val projectRef = db.collection("projects")
    val snapshot = projectRef.get().await()
    val docs = snapshot.documents
    docs.forEach {
        val project = it.toObject(Project::class.java)
        if (project != null) {
            projectList.add(project)
            Log.d("firebase listen", projectList.toString())
        }
    }

    return projectList

}
```

[firebase storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAXGR.png)

[firebase firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPhC8.png)

After i retrieve all projects with their photoUrl and other informations i want to display them in recycler view using ListAdapter. Title and description are displayed correctly in every recycler view item but it seems like this url can't be accessed by glide/ picasso . There is also a log line which shows photoUrl and if I click on it from logcat the browser displays correct image.

```
fun bind(project: Project) {
    binding.apply {
        Log.d("recycler view url", project.photoUrl)
        // Picasso.get().load(project.photoUrl).into(projectIv)
        Glide.with(binding.root).load(project.photoUrl).into(projectIv)
        titleTv.text = project.name
        descriptionTv.text = project.description
    }
    binding.executePendingBindings()
}
```

I have found some related topics but still haven't found working solution to that problem.

**EDIT**

Log result inside recyclerview bind method:

[Log resylt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5aeg.png)

After clicking on link:
[Link result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbcL6.png)

How it looks in my app:

[app screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax1FZ.jpg)

[app screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aFLG.jpg)

It looks like it only takes the photo size parameters but can't resolve the photo content, but i'm not sure

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Aside from that, have you seen this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46)? Here is also the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Comment: There are no errors. The main problem is with url i store in firestore, i guess. Log in RecyclerView Item bind method prints correct link - when i click on it it shows correct image in the browser, but it seems that i can't attach it to my ImageView becuse it shows only placeholder

Comment: When using `Log.d("recycler view url", project.photoUrl)`, are you getting the correct URL?

Comment: Yes, i also set one of my firestore projects url value to example photo url and it's also shown as placeholder. I will make edit of the main post where i show the links and how it looks in my app

Comment: So when you log the URL you have the correct value. Are you sure you it is not a problem related to the UI?

Comment: I suppose it's a problem with https format of url. I'll try to override some GlideModule methods to support https

Comment: @AlexMamo, you were right, i changed item layout and everything works fine.

Comment: Good to hear that you made it work ;)